# In App billing not fetching the purchases using queryPurchasesAsync

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

Currently I'm using the Play store library 6.1.x , but when I try to fetch the purchases using `queryPurchasesAsync` the subscriptions/in App purchases list are 0, the billing client is connected , however if I use also `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` I receive the list of the whole in app products and subscriptions, I uninstall and re install the app and it's the same, is any way to "force" the refresh of the cache from play store? the only solution seems to be "deleting cache from the Play Store app" but this is not the desired behaviour because if I update my app the users will lose the premium and currently I don't have any backend.
the code that I'm using :

```kotlin
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(ProductType.SUBS).build()) { billingResult, purchaseList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Timber.d("GoogleBilling query purchases size ${purchaseList.size}, items=${purchaseList}")

            } else {
                throw IllegalAccessException("GoogleBilling error fetching purchases  ${billingResult.toDescription()}"))
            }
        }
```

How I can solve this issue?